# An understanding problem about Ito's lemma .

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

According to ito's lemma:
$$\text{for}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f=(t,X_t)\ , \ \ dX_t=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t $$
 we get the formula:
$$df = \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right]dt\ +\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_t $$

so the convexity has an impact on the drift term. If $\ f $ is a concave function of $X_t$, then  $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ is negative, therefore the bigger the variation $\sigma^2$ is, the more it drags down the expectation of $\ f$ over time.
Anyone has an intuitive explanation for that?

Comment: Small typo: $dX_t=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t$. What do you mean by "expectation of $f$ over time"? $\mathbb E[f(t,X_t)]$? $f$ being concave down means that increasing $X_t$ won't necessarily contribute much in terms of increasing $f$, and could decrease $f$. E.g. $X_t=\sigma B_t$, $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$. As the BM walks large and positive, $f$ grows slowly and is limited in this case, but as the BM walks large and negative, $f$ goes even more negative.

Comment: Also, Jensen's inequality for a concave function reverses to become $E[f(X_t)]\leq f(E[X_t])$.